# RFID Arduino como colocar los datos al momento de reconocer una tarjeta

Tags: arduino

Al momento de pasar la tarjeta 1 por el lector RFID en el monitor serie, debe imprimir los datos. Pero cuando le paso la segunda tarjeta por el sensor me imprime la información de la primera y la segunda a la misma ves.
La tarjeta 1 y 2 ya están definidas.

```
boolean chekaKey(byte *serial)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<TARJETA1; i++)
    {
      Serial.println(" Nombre: Pablo");
      Serial.println(" Placa: BII-248");
      Serial.println(" CCI: 388-34543425");
      if(esIgual(serial, Autorizado[i]))
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<TARJETA2; i++)
    {
      Serial.println(" Nombre: Jose");
      Serial.println(" Placa: OLA-357");
      Serial.println(" CCI: 511-85395821");
          if(esIgual(serial, Autorizado2[i]))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Esta imagen es el screnshot del monitor serie
[image: Monitor serie después de haber pasado ambas tarjetas]

Answer (score 0):

Les has dado valores numéricos a las Tarjetas, por lo que se están cumpliendo la condición del bucle 1 y la del bucle 2.

```
 for(int i = 0; i<TARJETA1; i++)
 for(int i = 0; i<TARJETA2; i++)
```

Si TARJETA1 = 1 y TARJETA2 = 2, con tarjeta 2 cumples la condicion de i < TARJETA1 del primer bucle.

con la segunda tarjeta si se da cuneta en la imagen no le esta autorizando a la primera persona. solo muestra el contenido, pero solo autoriza a la segundo.

```
boolean chekaKey(byte *serial)
{
if(esIgual(serial, Autorizado[TARJETA1]))
    {
      Serial.println(" Nombre: Pablo");
      Serial.println(" Placa: BII-248");
      Serial.println(" CCI: 388-34543425");
        return true;
    }
      if(esIgual(serial, Autorizado2[TARJETA2]))
    {
      Serial.println(" Nombre: Jose");
      Serial.println(" Placa: OLA-357");
      Serial.println(" CCI: 511-85395821");

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Aunque me falta información sospecho que este código hará lo que usted quiere.

problema con los arrays

```
// lo que creo que tenias int Autorizado[2] = {00000,11111} donde 0000 es la correcta

// propongo

int Autorizado = 00000 //numero correcto de la tarjeta1
int Autorizado2 = 222222 //numero correcto de tarjeta2

    boolean chekaKey(byte *serial)
    {
    if(esIgual(serial, Autorizado))
        {
          Serial.println(" Nombre: Pablo");
          Serial.println(" Placa: BII-248");
          Serial.println(" CCI: 388-34543425");
            return true;
        }
          if(esIgual(serial, Autorizado2))
        {
          Serial.println(" Nombre: Jose");
          Serial.println(" Placa: OLA-357");
          Serial.println(" CCI: 511-85395821");

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Cuando lo hago de esa forma me sale solamente la información de la tarjeta 2 y la de la tarjeta ya no me sale.

Comment: Yo he comparado con TARJETA1 Y TARJETA2 pero realmente no se que valores tiene cada tarjeta. al haber echo un bucle TARJETA1 puede que no tenga un valor correcto. y sea menor. por eso en el bucle si que te funcionaba y ahora no. tienes que comprobar cual es el valor correcto de TARJETA1

Comment: Los valores de las tarjetas están definidas con 1

Comment: El valor de Autrorizado[1] es el que no esta bien asignado. te sugiero que cambies Autorizado [] y Autorizado2[] que son arrays, por variables. para evitarte problemas. tendras algo asi  int Autrorizado[3] ={ValorDelatarjeta,otroNumero, Otro.} ; sustituyelo por algo asi int Autorizado = valorDelatarjeta y luego en el if deja solo Autorizado. edito la respuesta para que lo veas mas claro.

Comment: //CLAVE DE LA TAJETA 1
byte Autorizado[TARJETA1][6] = {{0x05, 0xC8, 0x46, 0xE2, 0xFF, 0xFF, }};
// CLAVE DE LA TARJETA 2
byte Autorizado2[TARJETA2][6] = {{0xED, 0xB9, 0x55, 0xD3, 0xFF, 0xFF, }};  Estos son los valores de Autorizado